# Sublime Text 3 with SFTP package not mapping (syncing)

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext

**Background:**

I'm currently using sublime text 3 (free) and have installed the (free) sublime SFTP package and I'd like to work remotely on my server files. I saw a youtube video that this is possible by mapping remote -> local

**Steps taken**

1. I have created a folder (subfolder on my desktop)
2. dragged the folder into the sublime sidebar
3. setup the sftp config file (in the above folder) and set the remote_path for simplicity to just "/"
4. clicked on map remote -> local

**Status**

After it outputs that the connection is working:

```
Connecting to FTP server "xxx" as "yyyy@zzz.de" ... success
Validating remote folder "/" .... success
```

It's in an almost never ending loop with the status:

```
"Determining operations to sync remote path "/" down to local path "/Users/DS/Desktop/project_folder/3. Website/FTP/" ........."
```

I had let it run yesterday to see what happens and at some point after quite a while it did seem downloading but when I checked my folder it was still empty.

I have already checked the access rights of the folder (which is in a subfolder of my desktop) but it's fine. I have also clicked on "download folder" but this doesn't work either (just in the same loop).

At this point, I'm not sure what to do anymore. The connection is working, but it's just not mapping.

**Could anyone help me??**

Comment: Correction: just like [Sublime itself](https://www.sublimehq.com/store/text), the SFTP package [is commercial](https://codexns.io/products/sftp_for_sublime/buy) and must be purchased for continued use. However, both offer unrestricted tryout periods.

Comment: @MattDMo yep, I saw the price and Id purchase both, but without it working, it's a bit pointless :-(